# .NET LicenseManager license embedding for redistributable components

Tags: .net, user-controls, embedding

We are trying to use the .NET LicenseManger/Provider for our own custom component. However, it seems that this can't really be used if the licensed control will be wrapped in a 3rd party user control itself, since the saved license is always embedded in the control assembly in that case, which would force the consumer of that control to add licensing for our control again (which we consider as awkward...).

While LicenseContext#GetSavedLicenseKey allows to specify a different resource assembly, it's quite hard to find the correct assembly (walking the StackTrace is unreliable, scanning all loaded assemblies may take quite a while) - specifying null for the assembly only ever scans the main executing assembly, which does not contain a license resource in this scenario. Especially, I don't see how licensing for plugin dll will ever work.

So, what are other options that allow users of our component to wrap it and not have to redistribute our licensing information again?

Best regards
JM

Answer (score 0):

The .Net's LicenseProvider infrastructure does not support such scenarios.

The only option is to use some sort of "dynamic" licensing like providing a YourControl.LicenseKey property to allow your users to specify a license.